# mod_rewrite rule for CodeIgniter REST Server

Tags: .htaccess, codeigniter, mod-rewrite

I have developed a set of API that has the following folder structure.

```
- /api
  - config
  - controller
  - lib
  - .htaccess
```

The current rewrite rules in `.htaccess` look like this.

```
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} !-f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?url=$1 [QSA,L]
```

I am now adding some new APIs and I had like to use the [Phil Sturgeon CodeIgniter REST Server](https://github.com/philsturgeon/codeigniter-restserver) for these new APIs. I am adding them as a `/v2` folder in /api which makes the folder structure.

```
- /api
  - /config
  - /controller
  - /lib
  - .htaccess
  - /v2
    - # the CI REST Server files go here.
```

I need to add in some rewrite rules so that everything that goes to /api/v2 really does go there instead of being rewritten by my previous rule. I did the following but it doesnt seem to work, and I am guessing it's because it went into a loop.

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule ^v2/(.*)$ /api/v2/$1 [NC,L]

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} !-f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?url=$1 [QSA,L]
</IfModule>
```

How can I solve this, please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well if you just want to exclude real directories, so you can type in api/v2/ etc and it goes to that, try your htaccess file this way, if I'm understanding your requirement.

```
Options -Indexes
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?url=$1 [QSA,L]
```

Comment: thanks for the response, your method works. however it reduces the security a little, so if someone goes to /api/controller, he will be able to view all the files. is there a way to exclude real directories only for the /v2 folder?

Comment: What do you mean by view all the files? if you go to api/controller it lists the directory contents?

Comment: You could turn off indexing

Comment: Try that and see if that's what you need. See updated answer.

Comment: @user1258600 `if someone goes to /api/controller` It's better to put a `.htaccess` file containing `Deny from all` inside the private folders.

Comment: @HashemQolami we don't know how he plans to use the contents. He just wanted to prevent users seeing the contents of the folder. You can't access what you don't know. Disallowing listing should be sufficient as well.

Comment: That's why I noted *private folders* :)